# Using a for loop to create options for selector input?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am creating a drop down box with a list of all my user's initials. Right now my code is displaying all the users because I entered each user in manually.

**HTML**

```
<span id="msQuotedBySearch">
    <b>Filter by Initials: </b>
    <select id="msQuotedBy">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="ZR">ZR</option>
        <option value="TM">TM</option>
        <option value="jh">jh</option>
        <option value="TD">TD</option>
        <option value="LG">LG</option>
        <option value="BCS">BCS</option>
        <option value="DLH">DLH</option>
        <option value="jr">jr</option>
        <option value="CP">CP</option>
        <option value="LR">LR</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="TN">TN</option>
        <option value="DB">DB</option>
        <option value="TF">TF</option>
        <option value="dev">dev</option>
        <option value="BK">BK</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

This is not great code and was wondering how I could use a for loop to correctly add each user to the drop down menu.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
<span id="msQuotedBySearch">
    <b>Filter by Initials: </b>
    <select id="msQuotedBy">
        <option value="all">All</option>
            <% for user in @users
                initials = user.initials %>
                <option value=<%= initials %>><%= initials %></option>
            <% end %>
     </select>
</span>
```

but this just adds the very last user initial's from the database.

Any ideas on how I can add these list of initials from my database to the drop down menu in an easy way?

Comment: Are you manually creating this form in html or are you using rails for form templates (ie, form_tag, or form_for or form_with)

Comment: I was manually creating the form in html. If you think of a solution using the form templates I would be happy to see it.

Comment: why u do that. You need to use rails https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're super new to rails, and seemingly also StackOverflow, so welcome to both.

If you're using rails for your front end and not just a backend API, rails forms are usually created using form helpers.

So if you have used a beginner style scaffolding when creating your database model.  Typically there will be many of these models.  So lets use articles with a category name as an example.

```
rails generate scaffold category name:string url:string
rails generate scaffold article category:belongs_to name:string description:text status:integer
```

In addition to your data migration, and your model class, this also creates a controller, a route, and a set of restful views.

So in this Article example, in you app/views/articles/new.html.erb file you'll have something that looks like

```
 <h1>New Article</h1>

 <%= render 'form', article: @article %>

 <%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

And the actual form helper is in the partial form.html.erb

And if it's rails 5, it will be a form_with by default, rails 4 or less will say form_for

```
<%= form_with(model: article, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
   <%= form.label :category_id %>
   <%= form.text_field :category_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.number_field :status %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But for category, you want to display a select list, instead of having someone type in the ID of the category.  Because of rails form helper, which guesses which fields you want displayed, you'll just do

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :category_id %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```